# htaccess how to prioritize RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We recently migrate our new website and we need to adjust htaccess to avoid 404 error with the search engine,

The website was a Multilanguage site we decided to use session and cookie to manage multi language instead of string.

We put together  htaccess to make the changes

I have my htaccess code below

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/fr/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/en/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/es/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/pt/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ar/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^/?ar(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?pt(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?es(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?fr(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?en(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?location(.*)/(.*).html$ /newlocation$1/$2.html$3 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^/?ads/location(.*)/(.*).html$ /ads/newlocation$1/$2.html$3 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^/?page(.*)/(.*).html$ /newpage$1/$2.html$3 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^/?ads/page(.*)/(.*).html$ /ads/newpage$1/$2.html$3 [R=301,NE,L]
```

this code above works great ! but when I add this code below,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ads/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html?(.*)$ /ads/$1.html$2 [L,QSA]
```

Nothing is working anymore. Is there anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. I have put comments before new rules(at the bottom of your shown htaccess file), make sure these rules are there only. Place of rules is also very important in htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/fr/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/en/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/es/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/pt/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ar/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^/?ar(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?pt(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?es(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?fr(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?en(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?location(.*)/(.*).html$ /newlocation$1/$2.html$3 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^/?ads/location(.*)/(.*).html$ /ads/newlocation$1/$2.html$3 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^/?page(.*)/(.*).html$ /newpage$1/$2.html$3 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^/?ads/page(.*)/(.*).html$ /ads/newpage$1/$2.html$3 [R=301,NE,L]

##Your newly added rules fixed ones here....
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/ads/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html?(.*)$ /ads/$1.html$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @Celcoco, could you please do let me know if this has worked for you?